# Android-SDK Error Device Not Found

Tags: android, adb

I have been onto something in Android and it requires me to push some files in the adb. At first I pushed a file in the adb which worked fine but then after that as I tried to push other files in the adb it started to give me a device not found error. I tried killing the process both from the cmd and the Task Manager but it was of no help though after killing the server and again starting it the daemon is successfully loaded in port 5037. Though till now the project of mine works fine and the sdcard is read as I expect but I am hanged because no other files could be uploaded in the sdcard. :/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try restarting your system or logoff, maybe some port is blocked or some process is still running in the background.

Comment: I have been on this problem like for a week now...:/ so have restarted my system many times...

Comment: I am using ADT 20.0.2 already...:O

Comment: Would I need an update?? Its like 20.0.3 is available... but is it necessary??

Comment: that should be ok, android sdk also updated?

Comment: Sounds more like a driver/USB problem of your (unmentioned) OS.

Comment: There is no driver problem I have checked that too... OS is Windows 7... Android SDK is 10... could have gone too far from 7 which I am considering the base...

Comment: Could be that I need to connect the AVD with ADB for every push??

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen with my Nexus 4.

I was following

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

And I noticed that

```
C:\trythisworkspace>adb install bin\MyApp-debug.apk
error: device not found
error: device not found
error: device not found
- waiting for device -
^C
C:\trythisworkspace>
```

and

```
C:\trythisworkspace>adb devices
List of devices attached


C:\trythisworkspace>
```

So those are some symptoms for you

Go to device manager and see if like me you had a yellow exclamation mark

Download the google driver here  and extract it

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

then go to the device with yellow exclamation mark and properties and update driver and...browse.. and point it to google_usb_driver\usb_driver 
.

then it detected it and my device manager showed  "Android composite ADB interface".

BTW, Android SDK manager has an option to install google usb drivers. it's possible it puts them in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`
you could try pointing device manager to that if you find you have that directory.